# mysql UPDATE row containing highest value with data from another table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I've seen example for the other way round (update target table with highest value from subject).

I want to update table_A's row which has the highest `value` with data found in table_B.  Both have a common index.

Some tables might help.

Table A

```
+-------+----------+---------------+
| index | id_order | product_price |
+-------+----------+---------------+
|     1 |        1 | 10.00         |
|     2 |        1 | 12.00         |
|     3 |        2 | 5.00          |
|     4 |        3 | 4.00          |
+-------+----------+---------------+
```

Table B

```
+----------+------------------+
| id_order | price adjustment |
+----------+------------------+
|        1 | 4.00             |
|        2 | 1.00             |
|        3 | 2.00             |
+----------+------------------+
```

Table A - POST UPDATE

```
+-------+----------+---------------+
| index | id_order | product_price |
+-------+----------+---------------+
|     1 |        1 | 10.00         |
|     2 |        1 | 8.00          |
|     3 |        2 | 4.00          |
|     4 |        3 | 2.00          |
+-------+----------+---------------+
```

So row 2 (highest of order 1) has the adjustment applied but row 1 is left alone.  Rows 3 and 4 are each adjusted by their respected values as they are singletons.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a
SET value = (
    a.value - (
        SELECT value
        FROM b
        WHERE b.id = a.id
    )
)
WHERE a.id = 1
ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1
```

Everything should be as you want now, this is setting the value in table a where id = 1 to the value it has minus the value in table where id also is 1.

Comment: Forgive me, but that appears to be the opposite again.  You're selecting the max value from B and joining it to A, which is being updated.  What I want is to update the row of A which contains the max value, with some arbitrary value pulled from B.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I've added tables to the question.

Comment: does the value of "1" have to be hardcoded?  If so, it is impractical as I'm updating thousands of records.

Comment: I've tried serval things but can't seem to find a way to update all rows, since the thing that's making it hard is that you have to do it on the rows where the value is the highest. And not just all of them.

Comment: I agree its not easy :)   I am making some headway, although it isn't very efficient.  I'm pulling the matching ID to the row with the max value (grouped by its ID) into Table B then pushing the adjustment value back to table A